# Problems with loading of map tiles with leafletjs and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I want to create website with leaflet map placed in bootstap tab. If I switch into tab where is leaflet instantion tiles are not loading correct(I see the grey background). I guess there is a problem with size of `<div>` a because if resize the browsers window tiles load correctly. Any ideas? Here is my basic concept.

https://jsfiddle.net/rjper9nz/6/

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089541/leaflet-map-loading-half-greyed-tiles? and others  - just run `invalidateSize()` on the map instance when the parent container becomes visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger resize to window :

```
$(document).on('click','[href="#menu1"]',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    },300);
});
```

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rjper9nz/7/).