# Why isn't my map completely showing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am using Leaflet to display a map.
I just changed my HTML to use jQuery Mobile and Leaflet.

I read the documentation for jQuery Mobile, which says I have to add jQuery 1.11.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

But I was using:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
```

Why there is a such difference??

My problem is the following:

Before I moved to jQuery Mobile, my map was fully displaying in its container:

```
<div id="mapId"></div>
```

When I changed my HTML code to use jQuery Mobile, the layout was a disaster until I commented this out:

```
<!--  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>-->
```

and added this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

But now my map is not fully displaying. In fact I only see a very small part of it until I resize the browser:

[image]

After I resized the browser, the map is displaying fully.

Why and how can I solve this problem?
Why can't I use the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: can you please share some more code; like map related code.

Answer (score 5):

Same problem as in [Leaflet map loading half greyed tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089541/leaflet-map-loading-half-greyed-tiles) and related questions (e.g. [Leaflet Map not showing in bootstrap div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030949/leaflet-map-not-showing-in-bootstrap-div?rq=1), [Leaflet map not displayed properly inside tabbed panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762984/leaflet-map-not-displayed-properly-inside-tabbed-panel?rq=1), [leaflet map shows up grey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405189/leaflet-map-shows-up-grey?rq=1), etc etc) - just run `map.invalidateSize()` when your page layout is stable.

Comment: Great, thank a  lot. It seams to work. I will check more later!