# Leaflet map not Renderred completely until devtools is opened in browser -issue facing in angular version 10

Tags: angular, leaflet

[image]even after using `this.map.invalidateSize()` the map tiles are not loaded completely. this is working perfectly fine with the older version of angular 7 any workaround?

sample of the code:

```
@ViewChild('mapwindow', { static: false}) mapElement: any;
   
    this.map = L.map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
          center: [20.593684, 78.96288],
          zoom: 10,
          zoomControl: true,
          trackResize: true,
          layers: [osm]
        }); 
    const baseLayers = {
        OSM: osm,
        Satellite: googleSat,
        Hybrid: googleHybrid,
        Terrain: googleTerrain
    };
    L.control.layers(baseLayers, null, { position: "topright", collapsed: true }).addTo(this.map);

    this.map.invalidateSize();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [leaflet map does not appear correctly until resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53879753/leaflet-map-does-not-appear-correctly-until-resize)

Comment: Do you call invalidateSize _after_ the map container is mounted, displayed and has its final dimensions?

Comment: yes it is called after the map container in ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: At this point it would probably be best to provide a live reproduction example, typically on StackBlitz or CodeSandbox.