# Leaflet Map not fully loaded when i open inspect element it will load fully

Tags: javascript, user-interface, leaflet, maps, inspect

> Below is the function which call on onclick event

```
function drawMapFromWms(latt,longt){    

  document.getElementById('hrymap').innerHTML = "";      

     document.getElementById('hrymap').innerHTML = "<div id='map'></div>";
      map = L.map('map').setView([29.0,76.776695], 8);   


                 L.tileLayer.wms("http://example.com", {
             layers:'india3',

       format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
       attribution:"dummy"

    }).addTo(map);

          L.tileLayer.wms("http://example.com", {
             layers:'hrcm_roads',

       format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
       attribution:"dummy"

    }).addTo(map);

     var marker = L.marker([latt,longt]).addTo(map);

     $("#detail_content").css({'display':'block'});


  }
```

Here is the modal div which map div created

```
<div id="detail_content" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('detail_content').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-info">
          <div id="hrymap">
    </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> And finally function is call

Problem is when i click the button the map is loaded partially like below image
[image]

> and after inspect element it will loaded fully like below image.
>   [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my map completely showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742326/why-isnt-my-map-completely-showing)

Answer (score 1):

As it is created on the fly, your map may not be aware of the size of its container.

Try

```
map.invalidateSize();
```

Comment: Can you reorganize your code so that your map element is created when the page loads ? this will work (https://yafred.github.io/leaflet-tests/20161209-map-in-a-dialog/)

Comment: not working in this method also. dialog loaded perfetcly but map height width is not loaded fully

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout(function(){ map.invalidateSize(true)}, 300);

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the map correctly. You never set the center. Pass a map options argument as your second argument. Should be like:

```
var map = L.map('map', {center:[29.0, 76.776695], zoom:8});
```

Here's the [docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-example).

After reading your comment, I believe that it's because the CSS associated with the HTML `class` attribute is overriding your less specific CSS. Personally, I would just use more specific CSS, like:

```
div.modal-info>div#hrymap>div#map.leaflet-container{
  width:868px; height:650px;
}
```

instead of

```
#map{
  width:868px; height:650px;
}
```

By the way

```
document.getElementById('hrymap').innerHTML = "";
```

and

```
document.getElementById('hrymap').innerHTML = "<div id='map'></div>";
```

are both assignment. Why do the first one? And why not `$('#hrymap').html("<div id='map'></div>")`? When using jQuery, just use it.

If the CSS way doesn't work, try:

```
$("<div id='map'></div>").appendTo('#hrymap').css({width:'868px', height:'650px'});
```

Keep in mind that when using using `.appendTo()`, following jQuery methods will effect the jQuery selector before `.appendTo()`, while jQuery methods following `append()` would effect the `append()`.

Of course, once again, you should create the HTML structure as much as you can, without using JavaScript. Only do things on the fly when you have to.

Comment: i did same but its not working still same problem. Map loaded fully  when i open the inspect element

Comment: In my case map is loaded on boostrap modal may b that is creating a problem

Comment: when i tried to add appendTo then its give me an error identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Comment: I forgot the quotes. If you are putting that in a function that is getting called on a user event you may want to use `$('#hrymap').html('')` first, so you're not appending multiples of the same div, because `.appendTo` and `.append` are like `+=`.