# Leaflet map does not render tiles when route state change

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using leaflet to show some markers on map on my angular app.

When I first load the page the map shows ok, the problem is when I navigate to another page (with ui.router) and get back to the map page the tiles does not render anymore (all tiles are gray).

```
var map;
var all_coordinates;

function createMap(centrals) {
    // create the tile layer with correct attribution
    // set up the map
    map = new L.Map('map', {
        scrollWheelZoom: false
    });
    var baseMaps = {
        "Real Image": esri,
        "Roads": roads
    };
    roads.addTo(map);

    all_coordinates = SOME_COORDINATES;

    var overlayMaps = {"Name": SOME_LAYERS};
    L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
    //allCoordinates.push(L.latLng(37.016085, -7.933859));
    map.fitBounds(all_coordinates).addLayer(centrals_layers);
    return map;
}
```

Anyone has an ideia on what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the route config for the map page:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "/static/app/views/dashboard.html",
            controller: "homeController",
            resolve: {
                loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        {
                            serie: true,
                            files: ['/static/vendor/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
                                '/static/vendor/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css',
                                '/static/vendor/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js']
                        },
                        {
                            serie: true,
                            name: 'datatables',
                            files: ['/static/vendor/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js',]
                        },
                        {
                            serie: true,
                            name: 'datatables.buttons',
                            files: ['/static/vendor/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js',
                                '/static/vendor/datatables.net-buttons-bs/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css',
                                '/static/vendor/datatables.net-buttons-bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js',
                                '/static/vendor/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/buttons/angular-datatables.buttons.min.js']
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: I think your router config is more important to include than the map function. ui-router can do lots of things depending on the type of navigation you do, such as child routes, resolves, etc.

Comment: @cmonkey I will edit with te router for the map page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem as in [Leaflet map loading half greyed tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089541/leaflet-map-loading-half-greyed-tiles) and related questions (e.g. [Leaflet Map not showing in bootstrap div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030949/leaflet-map-not-showing-in-bootstrap-div?rq=1), [Leaflet map not displayed properly inside tabbed panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762984/leaflet-map-not-displayed-properly-inside-tabbed-panel?rq=1), [leaflet map shows up grey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405189/leaflet-map-shows-up-grey?rq=1), etc etc) - just run `map.invalidateSize()` when your page layout is stable.

Comment: Hi Ivan.. I've done that before writing this answer but with no luck. Just to be sure, should I add this line after initializing the map?

Comment: As I have said, run `map.invalidateSize()` **when your page layout is stable**. In your case, this means "when the UI router has finished making changes to the DOM".

Comment: The solution that I used was to use [angular-leaflet-directive](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/). I had a need to restructure the code and with this lib the problem was solved.
Thanks for your input, I didn't try adding the `map.invalidateSize()` when the layout is stable, but will assume it as the correct answer.